# Callback can not be obtained from the Webview in cocos2d-x(v3.10)

Tags: c++11, webview, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am in learning and trying to app development in the cocos2d-x.
How do I implement a callback from the WebView is?
I have been using the cocos2d-x v3.10.

test_index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="robots" content="none" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height">
</head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sp.js"></script>
    <ul class="slideshow">
        <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='sp.call("test1")'>
        <img src="img/test1.jpg" width="100%"/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <style>
        .bx-default-pager {
            display: none;
        }
        .bx-viewport {
            border: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>
```

sp.js

```
(function(){
    var sp = {};
    var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/);
    var isIOs = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/);
    sp.call = function(text){
        if(isAndroid){
            window.Cocos2dx.call(text);
        } else if (isIOs) {
            window.location.href = "cocos2dx:" + text;
        } else {
            window.location.href = text;
        }
    };
    window.sp = sp;
})();
```

test.cpp

```
bool TestScene::init()
{
        auto webView = cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView::create();
        webView->loadURL("http://test/test_index.html");
        webview->setONJSCallback(CC_CALLBACK_1(TestScene::callbackFromJS,this));
        webView->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));
        webView->setPosition(Point(0,150));
        webView->setContentSize(Size(WINSIZE.width,WINSIZE.height-150));
        this->addChild(webView,1);

}

void TestScene::callbackFromJS(cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView* webview, std::string* url)
{
  log("call this method");
}
```

Wrong use of the "setOnJSCallback"?

Comment: Is your project  setup to allow arbitrary loads from non https sites?

Comment: No, My Project can also access to the https.

Answer (score 1):

The JSCallback works like this.

It checks everytime a url is loaded, if that contains the JavascriptInterfaceScheme name if any defined for the webview. If it is there it wont load that url instead call the JSCallBack function. If not it will normally load the url. In @Plusmiles case you have not set any JavascriptInterfaceScheme name.

Below is the code which worked for me

```
cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView * Practice::_webView;
_webView = experimental::ui::WebView::create();
_webView->setContentSize(Size(1200, 1200));
_webView->setPosition(Vec2(900,768));
_webView->setJavascriptInterfaceScheme("cocos2dx");
_webView->loadURL("https://example.com");
_webView->setOnJSCallback(&Practice::callbackFromJS);
this->addChild(_webView, 1);


void Practice::callbackFromJS(cocos2d::experimental::ui::WebView* webview, const std::string &answer) {
     std::string response = answer;
}
```

to call from html file you need to set

```
window.location.href = "cocos2dx:" + text;
```

where cocos2dx is the JavascriptInterfaceScheme name set in the webview. Whenever it find this name in the url it will call the function with webview object as first parameter and url as second. So you need to avoid this webview in url if you want the url to load rather than calling JSCallback function.

I hope this answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

So you can only access "https" but not "http"? This is because of new IOS 9 restrictions. You need to add the following to your plist in order to be able to access http

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
       <!--Include to allow all connection -->   
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> 
   <true/> 
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank you, But There is already allowed "NSAllows Arbitrary Loads". Web Site can be loading. But I can not get a callback by pressing Web button.